# If $f\perp J=\{f - Uf\mid f \in H\}$ for unitary operator $U:H\to H$ and Hilbert space $H$, then does it immediately follow that $Uf=f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $U:H\to H$ a unitary operator, $I = \{f \in H\mid Uf = f\}$ and $J = \{f - Uf\mid f \in H\}$.

Full context and details to my question can be found in the proof of Lemma 3 in [this blogpost](https://joelmoreira.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/the-ergodic-theorem/).  I am trying to understand the details of the argument why $H = I\oplus J$. The author proves this by taking $f \in H:f\perp J$ and then writing

> $||f - Uf||^2 = ||f|^2 + ||Uf||^2 - 2\mathfrak{Re}(\left<f, Uf\right>) = 2||f||^2 - 2\mathfrak{Re}(\left<f, Uf\right>) - 2\mathfrak{Re}(\left<f, f - Uf\right>) = 2||f||^2 - 2\mathfrak{Re}(\left<f, f\right>) = 0.$

How is the jump to $2||f||^2$ justified in the second equality? Do we know a priori that $Uf = f$? But if $f \perp J \implies Uf = f$ then are any of the other steps necessary in the proof as wouldn't we then have that $||f - Uf||^2 = 0$?

Comment: The equality $\mathcal{H}=I\oplus J$ is not true, as the subspace $J$ is not necessarily closed. $\mathcal{H}=I\oplus \bar{J}$ holds always. The proof can be made easier. For a bounded operator $A$ there holds $\mathcal{H}=\ker A^*\oplus \bar{Im}A$ and the decomposition is orthogonal. Applying that to $A=Id-U$ gives the conclusion. Observe that $\ker (I-U^*)=\ker (I-U^{-1})=\ker (I-U).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every bounded unitary operator $U$ is an isometry, that is, $||Uf||=||f||$ for every $f\in H$.